# Handling throws with an ArithmaticException Constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor, throw

**Question:** Write a method called `addTwoPositive` that takes two int parameters, and if either value is not positive, throw an `ArithmeticException`, passing the String "Non-positive integers sent!" to the constructor of the exception. If the values are both positive, then return the sum of them.

I am confused as to how to handling this exception through the `ArithmeticException` constructor. Here is my code:

```
package IfnotPos;

public class IfNotPositive extends ArithmeticException{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException{

        IfNotPositive pos = new IfNotPositive();
        System.out.println(pos.addTwoPositive(-3,2));

    }

    public int addTwoPositive(int plus, int plus1) throws ArithmeticException{
        if(plus < 0 || plus1 < 0){
            throw new ArithmeticException("Non-positive integers sent!");

        }
        else{
            return plus + plus1;
        }

    }

    public ArithmeticException(String string) {
        return string;

    }

}
```

I get an error of "return type for the method is missing" and if I change it to string or anything else, it will obviously stop being a constructor. Any help handling this exception will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, all. So now I don't understand what they meant by "passing the String 'Non-positive integers sent!' to the constructor of the exception."

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to extend ArithmeticException class. You are not creating a custom exception, but writing a program to throw ArithmeticException (note this resides in java.lang) if a condition is not met.

Problem with your code is that constructor you have defined is never meant to be there and is not correct, hence the compiling issue.

```
public ArithmeticException(String string) {
    return string;
}
```

Just remove this constructor and you are good to go.

Comment: So now I don't understand what they meant by "passing the String 'Non-positive integers sent!' to the constructor of the exception."

Comment: Its just different ways of telling what to do - you can also understand it this way- "Throw an arithmetic exception with message 'Non-positive integers sent!'"

Answer (score 0):

From [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

**I get an error of "return type for the method is missing"**

You are getting this error because `public ArithmeticException(String string)` line in your code.

You can't add constructor of any other class inside another class, so Java treating `public ArithmeticException(String string)` as function rather constructor.

> And as you know for method you need to have return type mendetry

---

You don't have to extend, [ArithmeticException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) class.  See below code:

```
public class IfNotPositive{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException{

        IfNotPositive pos = new IfNotPositive();
        System.out.println(pos.addTwoPositive(-3,2));

    }

    public int addTwoPositive(int plus, int plus1) throws ArithmeticException{
        if(plus < 0 || plus1 < 0){
            throw new ArithmeticException("Non-positive integers sent!");

        }
        else{
            return plus + plus1;
        }

    }
}
```

---

> Q: throw an ArithmeticException, passing the String "Non-positive integers sent!"

It means throw `ArithmeticException` with detail message `"Non-positive integers sent!"`

So for that you can use [public ArithmeticException(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html#ArithmeticException(java.lang.String)) Constructor.

> Constructs an ArithmeticException with the specified detail message.

**Ex:**

```
throw new ArithmeticException("Non-positive integers sent!");
```

Comment: So now I don't understand what they meant by "passing the String 'Non-positive integers sent!' to the constructor of the exception."

Comment: @userb see the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to create constructor for ArithmeticException in your code?

```java
    public ArithmeticException(String string) {
        return string;

    }
```

You don't write a constructor like this. This is syntax exception complaining about the above method. This constructor is unnecessary. Remove this your code will work perfect. You should see below exception running your program...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-positive
>   integers sent!    at
>   com.code.samples.IfNotPositive.addTwoPositive(IfNotPositive.java:14)
>     at com.code.samples.IfNotPositive.main(IfNotPositive.java:8)

Comment: So now I don't understand what they meant by "passing the String 'Non-positive integers sent!' to the constructor of the exception."